# How do I capture local database changes when developing a WordPress site?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, git

I am currently building a website with WordPress. The workflow I am trying to follow is local -> staging -> production. However, WordPress seems to make this a bit tricky since many changes made in the WP GUI are saved to the database rather than updating local files.

For example, when I change the title of my homepage, that title is written to and then read from the database when the page loads. Same applies to any styling changes that I make from within the GUI, like text colors etc.

As a result, none of these changes can be pushed to staging using git, since git only looks for changes in the files, not changes in the database tables.

I know that I could make those changes on the staging server directly but if at all possible, I would rather keep development entirely local.

I also understand that I could export the local database and import it on the staging server but that would be terrible for many reasons.

So the question is, is there a method (and/or a tool) to capture changes to individual db tables and push them to the remote db, similar to how git handles file changes?

Comment: "I also understand that I could export the local database and import it on the staging server but that would be terrible for many reasons."  -- care to elaborate?  That's pretty much want any solution you get would do, isn't it, since the changes are in the database?

Comment: From my understanding, no, there is no way to do that. You need to migrate the the whole database.

Comment: @Kkinsey I think that's a bad idea because a) my local database's configuration is slightly different than the one on staging, and b) I would have to perform a migration every time I make an update (or at least periodically after making a set of updates. Either way, way too often. DB migrations should be kept to a minimum).

Also, I am not sure that that would be the only solution. That's why I asked the question. Could be that there's a tool out there that can detect db changes on specific tables only so a full migration can be avoided, no?

Comment: Well, I certainly understand not wishing to reinvent the wheel.  I'm probably oversimplifying this, but I think it could be done.  I don't know your setup, but here are a few pointers that would guide me:  1] mysqldump can dump specific tables, 2] git has post-commit hooks, and 3] I can probably script a solution that would dump and restore only the applicable tables, using scp(1) and ssh(1) in addition to mysqldump and git, which would run after a commit ...

Comment: Hm, sounds like a lot of effort. Well, at least for me it would be. I think I'm better served by just making all changes related to the database on the staging server directly. I wish I could avoid it but at least I won't have to deal with migrating databases, which would be potentially a pain in the neck once the site goes into production and users start signing up and doing stuff.

Comment: Hello @H. NetIrrigate do you have any update on this? Is there a solution?